# what is the technique to solve this type of integration

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int{\sqrt{x-3}(\sin^{-1}(\ln{x})+\cos^{-1}(\ln{x}))\ dx}$$
   what is the answer because I have a problem

Comment: Use latex to write the integral properly. Is it
$$\int \sqrt{x-3} \cdot {\sin^{-1}(\ln x)+\cos^{-1}(\ln x)}dx $$
?

Comment: @Reader: $\int \sqrt{x-3} \{\sin^{-1}(\ln x)+\cos^{-1}(\ln x)\}\mathrm{d}x$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that $\arccos a + \arcsin a =\frac {\pi}2$ for $0 \le a \le \frac {\pi}2$

Comment: What is the exact answer of this question

Comment: @PrashantGupta You can't integrate $\frac{\pi}2\int\sqrt{x-3}dx$?

Comment: @PrashantGupta Try substituting $\sqrt{x-3}=u$.